# What are the unreadable characters in Linux Anaconda install script?

Tags: shell-script, datascience-anaconda

The Anaconda for Linux installation scripts contain about 750 lines of a pretty straightforward set of bash commands, but they are then followed with 1.4 million lines of characters unreadable (at least in less and gedit).  What are these unreadable characters?

The scripts can be found here: https://www.continuum.io/downloads

...though they're rather large (These are the 32-bit versions for Linux.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the bash script that makes up the start of the file you will see it has a line like

```
tail -n +532 "$THIS_PATH" | tar xf - --no-same-owner
```

If you run `tail -n +532` on the file and pipe it into `file -` it will tell you the trailing data is

```
/dev/stdin: POSIX tar archive (GNU)
```

If you do the same tail piped into `tar tf -` you will see the tar contains many files like

```
pkgs/python-2.7.11-0.tar.bz2
```

which the script installs using its `extract_dist` function.